# Update part of model from scope selected object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model, angularjs-scope

Ok, I have model with one property(provider) as object. It can change at all.
There is example, where I change provider. There can be any parametrs, image can has dpi, json can has another parametr.
So, when I select anoter provider, how to merge model property(provider) and updated provider?

```
this.providerWasChange = function() {
     // here I should update model with provider parametrs(update full object)
     $scope.provider
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/77z165uj/11/

Hm,

```
var model = {
   id: '1',
   name: '',
   childModels: [{
       id: '1.1',
       name: 'item1',
       provider: {
           name: 'imageProvider'
           options: {
               transparent: false,
               dpi: 96
           }

       }
   }, {
       id: '1.2',
       name: 'item2'
       provider: {
           name: 'jsonProvider'
           options: {
               uppercase: true,
           }
       }
   }]
}

$scope.providers = [{
  name: 'jsonProvider',
  displayNmae: "jsonProvider", 
  options:{
      uppercase:$scope.providerOptions,
  }

}, {
  name: 'imageProvider',
  displayNmae: "imageProvider",
  options:{
      transparent:$scope.transparent,
      dpi::$scope.dpi
  }
}];

        _changeProvider = function(data) {
        if (data !== null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.providers.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.providers[i].name === data.name) {
                    $scope.providers[i].options = data.options
                    return $scope.providers[i];
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

I'm looking for a fuction or angular method, that set chosen provider blank with setted options from model back. For example, I'd like to change provider of item 2 to image provider(old values(if there is coincidence) should rewrites to model(item2), other should be deleted, and new - setted)

Comment: In addition to your link, it is beneficial to add more codes here to describe problem areas.

Comment: You need selected drop-down value in "$scope.provider"? Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: When I change provider, item.provider options should change dinamically, name of provider too, but stay observeable, if for example jsonProvider and imageProvider have same props.